# Find the change of basis matrix $P$ (say) for the change from the basis $B=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ to $B_1=\{ (1,1,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,1)\}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Find the change of basis matrix $P$ (say) for the change from the basis
$B=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ to
$B_1=\{ (1,1,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,1)\}.$

I am familiar with change of coordinate matrix.

My definition of change of coordinate matrix is:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space such that, $\beta$ and $\beta'$ are ordered bases for $V$ and $I_v$ is the identity linear transformation, i.e $I_V:V\to V$ such that $I_v(x)=x,\forall x\in V.$ The **change of coordinate matrix** is defined to be  the invertible matrix $Q=[I_v]_{\beta'}^{\beta}.$

But till now, never have I heard anything like, "change of basis matrix".

Assuming it to be synonymous with the notion of  "change of coordinate matrix" of a vector space, my solution goes like this:

Let $e_1=(1,1,0),e_2=(0,0,1)$ and $e_3=(0,1,1).$

We note that, $$I_v(1,0,0)=(1,0,0)=1e_1+1e_2-e_3,$$$$I_v(0,1,0)=0.e_1-e_2+e_3,$$ and $$I_v(0,0,1)=0e_1+1e_2+0e_3.$$ Thus, $P=[I_v]_{B}^{B_1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0\\ 1 && -1 && 1\\ -1 && 1 &&  0\end{pmatrix}.$

---

Now, I want to know whether my understanding along with my solution is valid? I need some clarification regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is valid, to check whether the result is correct you can consider the inverse map and its associated matrix:
$$Q:=[I_v^{-1}]_{B_1}^B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0\\ 1 && 0 && 1\\ 0 && 1 &&  1\end{pmatrix} $$
Since $I_v\circ I_v^{-1}=Id=I_v^{-1}\circ I_v$, you should have $PQ=I=QP$, which is true according to your computation.